# Unable to reach 172.x.x.x subnets across multiple internal networks

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

First things first, this is not an issue with the network, this is an issue with my laptop.

For the last several months I have been unable to reach any computers or local intranet websites in 172.x.x.x subnets. I'm a VoIP consultant and constantly work inside various enterprise networks and have experienced this issue on more than one separate customer network.

As far as I can tell nothing changed on my laptop, and I've even gone as far as re-installing Windows.

This is an example of my issue, I am unable to reach a server web GUI with the IP 172.23.232.22 or any other IP addresses in that subnet.

- I've tried creating a persistent route to this subnet, no luck.
- This issue seems to effect every Network adapter, wired, wireless, even over VPN.
- I've monitored my test pings via Wireshark and they seem to go to a black hole, I never see any ICMP packets when pinging any 172.x.x.x subnet
- I have been able to successfully reach a class B network by starting a VM, bridging my Ethernet connection to the VM, so it is something specific to this OS.

Here is some detailed info and troubleshooting:

```
Ping 172.23.232.22

Pinging 172.23.232.22 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Ping statistics for 172.23.232.22:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Tracert 172.23.232.22

Tracing route to 172.23.232.22 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
3     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-3A-4B-05-99-3A
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.23.75.136(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, January 8, 2015 9:30:56 AM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, January 16, 2015 11:23:15 AM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.23.74.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.13.24
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


Route Print

Interface List
15...00 ff 88 18 04 70 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
13...54 2e 81 6f 94 10 ......Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For Endpo
PN Client
12...86 3a 4b 05 99 3a ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
7...20 68 9d 2a d8 5e ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
5...84 3a 4b 05 99 3b ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
4...84 3a 4b 05 99 3a ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
3...3c 97 0e 58 ec 4d ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
9...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
11...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
32...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
31...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #14
44...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #15
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table

Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.23.74.1     10.23.75.136     25
       10.23.74.0    255.255.254.0         On-link      10.23.75.136    281
     10.23.75.136  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.23.75.136    281
     10.23.75.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.23.75.136    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.26.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.26.1    276
     192.168.26.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.26.1    276
   192.168.26.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.26.1    276
    192.168.164.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
    192.168.164.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
  192.168.164.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.23.75.136    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.26.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.23.75.136    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.26.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276

===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
IPv6 Route Table

Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 11    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    276 fe80::967:4aa2:ae4b:3c55/128
                                On-link
 11    276 fe80::50c9:810b:5d06:c4a5/128
                                On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    276 ff00::/8                 On-link

===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What command, exactly, did you use to create a persistent route?

Comment: Something like this. I've done direct routes to that IP, and routes to that IP's subnet.

    route -p add 172.23.232.22 255.255.255.255 10.23.74.1 metric 3 if 4

Comment: It strikes me as a little odd that your gateway hop doesn't show up in the tracert. Also your DHCP server of 1.1.1.1 is very odd?

Comment: Completely agree it is odd, it doesn't show that in the tracert, the packets don't show in Wireshark, some blackhole its it. Nevermind the DHCP, there was a second DHCP server that got cut off. I'm adding it now.